# wp_query in add_action( 'admin_notices'

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type - "data-result" of which there are 5 published posts.

I have another post type "data-collection-tool" that creates a "data-result" post from the front end when a user visits/edits a 'data-collection-tool' post and this works well.

I want to display a notice in the dashboard when the admin tries to edit a "data-collection-tool" post but where there a one or more "data-result" posts.

Code

```
function ws48356743_warn_questionnaire_editor() {

if(get_post_type() == 'data-collection-tool' ){
    ?>
    <div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'Done! '.wp_98435409_checkResultsExist(get_the_ID()), 'sample-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'ws48356743_warn_questionnaire_editor',1,0 );
```

To do this I am querying "data-result" in a separate function:

```
function wp_98435409_checkResultsExist(){

$args_n = array( 
    'post_type ' => 'data-result',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 9999

);
$p = get_posts($args_n);
print_r($p);

wp_reset_postdata();


}
```

get_posts returns an empty array and I can't figure out why.

All of the above code runs in functions.php

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: `numberposts` is deprecated, please use `posts_per_page` http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36979

Comment: Thanks hadn't spotted that. Question updated but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

A rogue space stopped this working

```
$args_n = array( 
  'post_type' => 'data-result', // <- was here in 'post_type '
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page'    => 9999

);
```